# Download a file from the stock exchange website

Tags: php, curl, download

I have to download a file from the stock exchange website through php, the link of the file is given below,

I found many codes in google but not working, Anyone who have had gone through it?

**Link**:

> https://psx.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20170119_new.lis.Z&l=Hd

Comment: where is the link?? what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://psx.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20170119_new.lis.Z&l=Hd

Comment: have you tried fopen?
have you tried dl()?

Comment: have you even tried *anything at all*?

Comment: I have tried many codes  by using curl and ftp but didn't work. I don't know which link I should put in the code either file dynamic link or website link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this helps you.

```
$url="https://psx.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20170119_new.lis.Z&l=Hd";
    header('Content-type: application/zip');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.zip"');

    readfile($url);
```